# How to measure distance between two data in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Calculate the distance between the position of each element in a list1 and the position of the same element in list2 then find the normalized distance in vhdl
First, we will make mem1 (consist of addresses for every data input) i.e address from 1,2,3,4.... to end of the mem1 data input,ok
mem2 (consist of addresses for every data input ) i.e address from 1,2,3,4.... t0 end of the mem2 data input,ok
Check if any of the data input from mem1 = any data input from mem2 .
I.e. The position of each element in mem1 and the position of the same element in mem2
So the address to the same element will be different in the two mem
The address difference will be the distance measure.
I.e searching for similarity, the compute the distance between list1 and list2
How I can do this in vhdl code???
Any help please???

Comment: Does this need to be synthesisable?  If so, what are your performance goals?  How big are the  lists, and how many comparisons do you need to achieve? There are many trade-offs which will influence the performance and size of any solution.

Comment: yes nedd to be synthesisable, we try to do that but i want to know is it correct?first we need to have a ram component. can use inference as below or instantiate it is simple dual (separate read addr/write addr)

Comment: You still need some performance goals and information on how big the lists are.  If they are small, you could just build it out of logic.  If they are large, you need to use internal memory for storage.  If they are huge you'll need external memory and probably a clever access pattern/caching to maximise the use of the external bandwidth

Comment: hi martin ,the two table will be array (0 to 255) of std_logic_vector(0 to 7),i will use fbga internal ram, i will compute the distance between(s1,s2),(s1,s3)and (s2,s3) and find average value then use it for another things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach sounds logical.  I would design a single entity that instantiated a piece of memory.  The input would be the data that you are looking for.  The output would be the location of the data, and a signal indicating if the data was found or not.  It would take a number of clock cycles to read out all of the data from the memory.  The number of clock cycles would be equal to the depth of the memory.  So if you have 10 data words in your memory, it would take 10 clocks to read through all of the words.

There are corner cases that you should consider... what if the data word is in the memory twice?  Is the data stored in the memory in sequential order?

Once you've figured all of this out, instantiate two of these components inside a higher level file.  This file does the calculation of the distance between the two data locations.

This is just how I would tackle it conceptually.  Good luck.

Comment: there isn't duplicate word,table1 is some samples taken from user A represent in trigraphs from any text he wrote and digit behind it be the time he take to type those trigraphs such as ( acs--125 ms, asd--200 ms ........) build a sorted table1(S1) ,(sorted according to the time),table2 (S2) of the same trigraphs but in different location compare between these samples and found the distance between the same trigraphs from the two samples, i.e  I.e. The position of each element in s1 and the position of the same element in s2 ,d(s1,s2), i should make it in vhdl code ,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to produce an array containing the distances from each element in array_1 to the element holding the same value in array_2.

If so, here's a first stab at a possible solution:

```
function individual_distances(vector_1, vector_2: integer_vector) return integer_vector is
    variable distances: integer_vector(vector_1'range);
begin
    for i in vector_1'range loop
        for j in vector_2'range loop
            if (vector_1(i) = vector_2(j)) then
                distances(i) := j - i;
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;

    return distances;
end;
```

Here's a sample output for a few random arrays:

```
individual_distances( (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 3, 2, 1) );  --> (4, 2, 0, -2, -4)
individual_distances( (1, 2, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 1) );        --> (3, 1, -1, -3)
individual_distances( (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3) );              --> (0, 0, 0)
```

As Martin Thompson noted, whether this solution is usable in your case depends on your performance goals and the size of the lists. In practice, this could work for small to medium-sized lists. If your lists are large, you should study architectural choices. For instance, a fully serialized version of the algorithm would take N^2 clock cycles. The example below takes 64 cycles to compute the distances between two arrays with 8 elements each:

```
process (clock, reset) is
    variable i, j: integer range 0 to 7;
begin
    if reset then
        i := 0;
        j := 0;
        distances <= (others => 0);
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        if (vector_1(i) = vector_2(j)) then
            distances(i) <= abs(j - i);
        end if;
        if i < 7 then
            i := i + 1;
        else
            i := 0;
            j := (j + 1) mod 8;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Other intermediate solutions exist, such as serializing only the outer loop. If you need performance, you could also consider pipelining.

The above code is synthesizable, just remember to constrain the ranges as per your design requirements.

Comment: yes ,you are right rick ,but if the vectors is std_logic_vector (0 to 7) how will be the Type of distances is incompatible with type of -.

Comment: You can easily convert from std_logic_vector to integer using the function to_integer(slv) defined in package ieee.numeric_std.

Comment: how can i make your solution for ram,rick,this is for shift register

Comment: The suggestion above can be used for any kind of array, it doesn't matter whether it's a RAM or a shift register. Anyway, you can't use it as is for a typical RAM with a single read port. In that case, the easiest way is to calculate one distance value for every clock edge.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a serialized version. This version reads only one element of each vector at a time and is suitable for an implementation where each input vector is stored in a synchronous block RAM. Now it's your job to figure the details. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

i make a code as your suggestion rick, but i have the same problem ,what is the mistake Type of distances is incompatible with type of -

```
 library IEEE;
```

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package samples is
type sample is array( 0 to 255) of std_logic_vector (0 to 7);

end samples;

```
entity measure is
```

port(
     clk:std_logic;
      A1: in sample;
      A2: in sample;
      distance: out sample);
end measure;
architecture Behavioral of measure is
signal d: sample ;
function distances(A1, A2: sample) return sample is
    variable distances: sample;
begin
    for i in A1'range loop
        for j in A2'range loop
            if (A1(i) = A2(j)) then
                distances :=  (j - i);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;

```
return distances;
```

end;
end behavioral;